# SSH not connecting after updating C library /bin/bash not found

Tags: ssh, glibc

I recently updated my C library, and since then I cannot connect to my PC via SSH.

```
$ ssh user@foobarzo.com 
user@foobarzo.coms password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Tue Aug 15 14:30:30 BRT 2017

  System load:  0.0                Processes:           648
  Usage of /:   0.2% of 761.73GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 0%                 IP address for eth0: 1.44.190.1485
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for tun0: 192.168.0.6

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

131 packages can be updated.
90 updates are security updates.

New release '16.04.3 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Tue Aug 15 15:39:20 2017 from 192.168.0.1
/bin/bash: No such file or directory
**Connection to foobarzoo.com closed.**
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Updated your C library how, exactly? FWIW it looks like it **is** connecting - but failing to execute your login shell

Comment: What do you mean "I recently updated my C library" ? What and how did you do that ?

Comment: Could be any number of problems, chroot ? See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2031679 for the sort of information we need (ldd /bin/bash)

Comment: I used this command : **dpkg -r --force-all libc6** , after this  closed my ssh conection

Comment: Forcibly removing `libc6` will have pretty much hosed your system I think

Comment: Someone told you that command would "update your C library"? Unfriend them... and reinstall

Answer (score 2):

*A word of advice before I start with the actual answer: `dpkg` (and many other commands) print warning messages and refuse to perform dangerous or idiotic tasks for a reason. Don’t use options starting with `--force` unless you know **exactly** what you’re doing or trust in the competence and good will of the person telling you to do it!*

---

If you have *physical* access to the machine in question (from which you removed `libc6`) you can use a live system to extract a temporary installation of `libc6` which should allow you to boot the system and use a package manager to reinstall it properly:

1. *Boot* a live system (from USB or DVD) and *mount* the root file system(s) of the broken installation. Let’s assume it’s mounted at `/media/ubuntu/root`.
2. *Download* the most recent version of the `libc6` package for your Ubuntu release and architecture, e. g. from [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) or [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libc6).
3. *Extract* the package into the previously mounted file system:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-deb -x libc6_2.23-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb /media/ubuntu/root
   ```

   Adjust the package file name and extraction path to your situation.
4. Reboot into the Ubuntu installation and ask Apt to fix missing packages and specifically reinstall the `libc6` package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall libc6
   ```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer, but on moment i don't have access physical to machine, only remote, but i go follow your recomendations.